# Error compiling with gralloc_priv.h file

Tags: c++

New to programming so be easy on me. I'm receiving an error while compiling for an AOSP rom. I'm doing all of this on Ubuntu 12.04 kernel 3.2.0.29 if that helps any.

This is the error I'm receiving:

> device/lge/c800/include/gralloc_priv.h: In member function 'T& Queue::getHeadValue()\     > const':
>   device/lge/c800/include/gralloc_priv.h:169:55: error: there are no arguments to 'LOGE' that > depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'LOGE' must be available [-fpermissive]
>   device/lge/c800/include/gralloc_priv.h:169:55: note: (if you use '-fpermissive', G++ will   > accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)

This is the section of code that it relates to in the header file:

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2008 The Android Open Source Project
 * Copyright (c) 2011-2012, Code Aurora Forum. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

#ifndef GRALLOC_PRIV_H_
#define GRALLOC_PRIV_H_

#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <sys/cdefs.h>
#include <hardware/gralloc.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <cutils/native_handle.h>

#include <linux/fb.h>

#if defined(__cplusplus) && defined(HDMI_DUAL_DISPLAY)
#include "overlayLib.h"
using namespace overlay;
#endif

enum {
    /* gralloc usage bits indicating the type
     * of allocation that should be used */

    /* ADSP heap is deprecated, use only if using pmem */
    GRALLOC_USAGE_PRIVATE_ADSP_HEAP       =       GRALLOC_USAGE_PRIVATE_0,
    /* SF heap is used for application buffers, is not secured */
    GRALLOC_USAGE_PRIVATE_UI_CONTIG_HEAP  =       GRALLOC_USAGE_PRIVATE_1,
    /* SMI heap is deprecated, use only if using pmem */
    GRALLOC_USAGE_PRIVATE_SMI_HEAP        =       GRALLOC_USAGE_PRIVATE_2,
    /* SYSTEM heap comes from kernel vmalloc,
     * can never be uncached, is not secured*/
    GRALLOC_USAGE_PRIVATE_SYSTEM_HEAP     =       GRALLOC_USAGE_PRIVATE_3,
    /* IOMMU heap comes from manually allocated pages,
     * can be cached/uncached, is not secured */
    GRALLOC_USAGE_PRIVATE_IOMMU_HEAP      =       0x01000000,
    /* MM heap is a carveout heap for video, can be secured*/
    GRALLOC_USAGE_PRIVATE_MM_HEAP         =       0x02000000,
    /* WRITEBACK heap is a carveout heap for writeback, can be secured*/
    GRALLOC_USAGE_PRIVATE_WRITEBACK_HEAP  =       0x04000000,
    /* CAMERA heap is a carveout heap for camera, is not secured*/
    GRALLOC_USAGE_PRIVATE_CAMERA_HEAP     =       0x08000000,

    /* Set this for allocating uncached memory (using O_DSYNC)
     * cannot be used with noncontiguous heaps */
    GRALLOC_USAGE_PRIVATE_UNCACHED        =       0x00100000,

    /* This flag needs to be set when using a non-contiguous heap from ION.
     * If not set, the system heap is assumed to be coming from ashmem
     */
    GRALLOC_USAGE_PRIVATE_ION             =       0x00200000,

    /* This flag can be set to disable genlock synchronization
     * for the gralloc buffer. If this flag is set the caller
     * is required to perform explicit synchronization.
     * WARNING - flag is outside the standard PRIVATE region
     * and may need to be moved if the gralloc API changes
     */
    GRALLOC_USAGE_PRIVATE_UNSYNCHRONIZED  =       0X00400000,

    /* Set this flag when you need to avoid mapping the memory in userspace */
    GRALLOC_USAGE_PRIVATE_DO_NOT_MAP      =       0X00800000,

    /* Buffer content should be displayed on an external display only */
    GRALLOC_USAGE_EXTERNAL_ONLY           =       0x00010000,

    /* Only this buffer content should be displayed on external, even if
     * other EXTERNAL_ONLY buffers are available. Used during suspend.
     */
    GRALLOC_USAGE_EXTERNAL_BLOCK          =       0x00020000,
};

enum {
    /* Gralloc perform enums
    */
    GRALLOC_MODULE_PERFORM_CREATE_HANDLE_FROM_BUFFER = 0x080000001,
};


enum {
    GPU_COMPOSITION,
    C2D_COMPOSITION,
    MDP_COMPOSITION,
    CPU_COMPOSITION,
};

/* numbers of max buffers for page flipping */
#define NUM_FRAMEBUFFERS_MIN 2
#define NUM_FRAMEBUFFERS_MAX 3

/* number of default bufers for page flipping */
#define NUM_DEF_FRAME_BUFFERS 2
#define NO_SURFACEFLINGER_SWAPINTERVAL
#define INTERLACE_MASK 0x80
#define S3D_FORMAT_MASK 0xFF000
#define COLOR_FORMAT(x) (x & 0xFFF) // Max range for colorFormats is 0 - FFF
#define DEVICE_PMEM "/dev/pmem"
#define DEVICE_PMEM_ADSP "/dev/pmem_adsp"
#define DEVICE_PMEM_SMIPOOL "/dev/pmem_smipool"
/*****************************************************************************/
#ifdef __cplusplus

//XXX: Remove framebuffer specific classes and defines to a different header
template <class T>
struct Node
{
    T data;
    Node<T> *next;
};


template <class T>
struct Node
{
    T data;
    Node<T> *next;
};

template <class T>
class Queue
{
public:
    Queue(): front(NULL), back(NULL), len(0) {dummy = new T;}
    ~Queue()
    {
        clear();
        delete dummy;
    }
    void push(const T& item)   //add an item to the back of the queue
    {
        if(len != 0) {         //if the queue is not empty
            back->next = new Node<T>; //create a new node
            back = back->next; //set the new node as the back node
            back->data = item;
            back->next = NULL;
        } else {
            back = new Node<T>;
            back->data = item;
            back->next = NULL;
            front = back;
       }
       len++;
    }
    void pop()                 //remove the first item from the queue
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            return;            //if the queue is empty, no node to dequeue
        T item = front->data;
        Node<T> *tmp = front;
        front = front->next;
        delete tmp;
        if(front == NULL)      //if the queue is empty, update the back pointer
            back = NULL;
        len--;
        return;
    }
    T& getHeadValue() const    //return the value of the first item in the queue
    {                          //without modification to the structure
        if (isEmpty()) {
            LOGE("Error can't get head of empty queue");
            return *dummy;
        }
        return front->data;
    }

    bool isEmpty() const       //returns true if no elements are in the queue
    {
        return (front == NULL);
    }

    size_t size() const        //returns the amount of elements in the queue
    {
        return len;
    }
```

If anyone can help with this error and explain it to me would be very helpful. If more info is needed I will post whatever is needed. I will probably be posting a few more errors here but wanted to see how I do with this first post. Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: This is something to do with Android right? I think the error message is telling you (in an incredibly unhelpful way) that you haven't declared the macro/function LOGE. It's probably just a matter of including the right header file. Or since LOGE doesn't seem to be central to whatever it is you are trying to do, you could just replace LOGE with another error logging mechanism.

Comment: Update: I added the beginning of the file. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and include `#include <cutils/log.h>` in your code before `gralloc_priv.h`?

or compile with parameter `-fpermissive` as the error output suggests.

Comment: I did add the '#include <cutils/log.h> and still the same error. Where do I add the -fpermissive? The command I'm using to compile is '. build/envsetup.sh && brunch c800'.

Comment: Please check at following links:

http://git.linaro.org/gitweb?p=people/chunsangjeong/gralloc-dev.git;a=commitdiff;h=9719fb0926d2a49f7c3fb9ccca65f0437253b8c6
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.4/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html

To fix it, modify external/gtest/src/Android.mk, for gtest-all.cc ( and 
probably gtest_main.cc ): 
`-LOCAL_CFLAGS += -O0`
`+LOCAL_CFLAGS += -O0 -fpermissive`

Above is a direct copy paste, I haven't tested it myself.

Comment: I copied and pasted into the Android.mk file I have and still get the same error and actually adds a couple more errors. Not sure what else to do. I will check the links you provided and see if that helps. Thanks Abhinav.

Comment: I noticed that in the beginning of the build it states that it cant find 'src': No such file or directory. Could this be my problem being that src holds the Android.mk file

Comment: Ok got past the error by typing in an 'A' in front of 'LOGE' wherever it came up in the header file. Now I have a new error where I'll start in another question. Thanks guys for your help! Much appreciated.