# Issues compiling for android...'Was not declared in this scope' error

Tags: android, c++

Hello guys another C++ programming question. Again be easy on me as I'm just starting to learn C++. I'm getting an error at compile time that shows:

> frameworks/native/libs/gui/SurfaceTextureClient.cpp: In member function 'virtual int >android::SurfaceTextureClient::setUsage(uint32_t)':
>   frameworks/native/libs/gui/SurfaceTextureClient.cpp:498:20: error: >'GRALLOC_USAGE_PRIVATE_EXTERNAL_ONLY' was not declared in this scope
>   frameworks/native/libs/gui/SurfaceTextureClient.cpp:503:23: error: >'GRALLOC_USAGE_PRIVATE_EXTERNAL_BLOCK' was not declared in this scope
>   frameworks/native/libs/gui/SurfaceTextureClient.cpp:505:30: error: >'GRALLOC_USAGE_PRIVATE_EXTERNAL_CC' was not declared in this scope

Here is the 'SurfaceTextureClient.cpp' file:

```
 17 #define LOG_TAG "SurfaceTextureClient"
 18 #define ATRACE_TAG ATRACE_TAG_GRAPHICS
 19 //#define LOG_NDEBUG 0
 20
 21 #include <android/native_window.h>
 22 
 23 #include <utils/Log.h>
 24 #include <utils/Trace.h>
 25
 26 #include <gui/ISurfaceComposer.h>
 27 #include <gui/SurfaceComposerClient.h>
 28 #include <gui/SurfaceTexture.h>
 29 #include <gui/SurfaceTextureClient.h>
 30
 31 #include <private/gui/ComposerService.h>
 32 #ifdef QCOMHW
 33 #include <gralloc_priv.h>
 34 #endif
 35 
 36 namespace android {
 37 
 38 SurfaceTextureClient::SurfaceTextureClient(
 39         const sp<ISurfaceTexture>& surfaceTexture)
 40 {
 41     SurfaceTextureClient::init();
 42     SurfaceTextureClient::setISurfaceTexture(surfaceTexture);
 43 }
 44 
 45 // see SurfaceTextureClient.h
 46 SurfaceTextureClient::SurfaceTextureClient(const
 47          sp<SurfaceTexture>& surfaceTexture)
 48 {
 49     SurfaceTextureClient::init();
 50     SurfaceTextureClient::setISurfaceTexture(surfaceTexture->getBufferQueue());
 51 }
 52
 53 SurfaceTextureClient::SurfaceTextureClient() {
 54     SurfaceTextureClient::init();
 55 }
 56 
 57 SurfaceTextureClient::~SurfaceTextureClient() { 
 58     if (mConnectedToCpu) {
 59         SurfaceTextureClient::disconnect(NATIVE_WINDOW_API_CPU);
 60
 61 }

494 int SurfaceTextureClient::setUsage(uint32_t reqUsage)
493 {
494     ALOGV("SurfaceTextureClient::setUsage");
495     Mutex::Autolock lock(mMutex);
496 
497 #ifdef QCOMHW
498     if (reqUsage & GRALLOC_USAGE_PRIVATE_EXTERNAL_ONLY) {
499         //Set explicitly, since reqUsage may have other values.
500         mReqExtUsage = GRALLOC_USAGE_PRIVATE_EXTERNAL_ONLY;
501         //This flag is never independent. Always an add-on to
502         //GRALLOC_USAGE_EXTERNAL_ONLY
503         if(reqUsage & GRALLOC_USAGE_PRIVATE_EXTERNAL_BLOCK) {
504             mReqExtUsage |= GRALLOC_USAGE_PRIVATE_EXTERNAL_BLOCK;
505         } else if(reqUsage & GRALLOC_USAGE_PRIVATE_EXTERNAL_CC) {
506             mReqExtUsage |= GRALLOC_USAGE_PRIVATE_EXTERNAL_CC;
507         }
508     }
509 #endif
```

If more info is needed let me know. Fixed a previous error with this compile. Not sure what to do here with this one.

Comment: Where is `GRALLOC_USAGE_PRIVATE_EXTERNAL_ONLY` declared?

Comment: Here is the link to a previous post with the gralloc... header file:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923550/error-compiling-with-gralloc-priv-h-file

Comment: Well.. in that file you dont have `GRALLOC_USAGE_PRIVATE_EXTERNAL_ONLY`, but only `GRALLOC_USAGE_EXTERNAL_ONLY`

Comment: Not sure what to do from here. Should I assume a missing header?

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the solution to the problem I think lol. There was another gralloc_priv.h file in  source folder under a different directory and copied over the declarations in that header file for the unscoped members and it went through fine. If anyone is coming across this problem let me know and I'll show you where I found the files.

Comment: If you find your own answer to your question, edit the question and add your answer to that.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Actually, that's what is _not_ wanted on this site. But we would like to have complete answers, rather than "I think I solved it, ask if you want details".

Comment: @stefan Apologise, checked out the Etiquette. I thought that was a no no on here and you were supposed to add your own answer as part of your question. I will not make that mistake again. Thanks.